# Python subprocess with double quote and whitespace for django command

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I am using this [node plugin](https://github.com/logandk/serverless-wsgi#remote-command-execution) to run django management commands.

If I execute the command directly, it works:

```
sls wsgi manage local -c "check --list-tags"
```

If I call a python script that calls it as a subprocess, It cannot find the command:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sls', 'wsgi', 'manage', 'local', '-c', '"check --list-tags"'])
(out, err) = proc.communicate()


"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py\", line 102, in call_command\n    app_name = get_commands()[command_name]\nKeyError: 'check --list-tags'\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"./wsgi_handl
    er.py\", line 89, in handler\n    management.call_command(*shlex.split(meta.get(\"data\", \"\")))\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py\", line 104, in call_command\n    raise CommandError(\"Unknown command: %r\" % command_name)\ndjango.core.management.base.CommandError: Unknown command: 'check --list-tags'\n
    "
```

If I do a command that does not contain any whitespace it works, such as:

```
subprocess.Popen(['sls', 'wsgi', 'manage', 'local', '-c', '"makemigrations"'])
```

Comment: have you tried proc = subprocess.Popen(['sls', 'wsgi', 'manage', 'local', '-c', '"check', '--list-tags"'])

Comment: This throws `ValueError: No closing quotation` from shlex

Comment: you can pass the full command as a string if you use shell=True, try that and refine it later proc = subprocess.Popen('sls wsgi manage local -c "check --list-tags"' shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!

Comment: will post answer and you accept it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the full command as a string if you use shell=True, try that and refine it later

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    'sls wsgi manage local -c "check --list-tags"',
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)
```